# plotting each column of a matrix individually in a single graph in R

Tags: r, plot

[image]I have a 10x10 matrix and I want to plot each column(in the form of lines) in the following way
1. There should be one y-axis which will cover the scale of all columns of matrix.
2. There should be single x-axis with 10 points(= the number of columns).
3. the first column of matrix should be plotted within the point-1 and point-2 of x-axis, the second column of matrix within the point 2 and point-3, third column within the point-3 and point-4 and so on....
I have seen already posts, but all are multiple plots which are not according to my requirements. Could you please help me that how this can be done in R

Comment: check out `?matplot()`

Comment: How can I plot with matplot() to fulfill  point 3 in above description

Answer (score 3):

You could convert your data from wide to long format and then use a standard plotting utility like `ggplot` to appropriately group your data and position it:

```
# Build a sample matrix, dat
set.seed(144)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100), nrow=10)

# Build a data frame, to.plot, where each element represents one value in the matrix
to.plot <- expand.grid(row=factor(seq(nrow(dat))), col=factor(seq(ncol(dat))))
to.plot$dat <- dat[cbind(to.plot$row, to.plot$col)]
to.plot$col <- as.factor(to.plot$col)

# Plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(to.plot, aes(x=as.numeric(col)+(row-1)/max(row), y=dat, group=col, col=col))
 + geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:10) + xlab("Column")
```

[image]

Comment: I have added an example(drawn in paint) for further clarification what type of graph I want...I just added 6 columns...but in actual..I need 10 in a similar form

Comment: thats great...is it possible to make a code without using ggplot2...latter I may need to plot same columns of two or more matrices in one plot...for examples col1 of two matrices ...adjust their colors and and style...I heard that similar graphs can be made with lines() without using ggplot..but I don't know how

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it with matplot.

```
matplot(y = myData,
       ,x = matrix(seq(prod(dim(myData)))/nrow(myData),
                   nrow=nrow(myData),byrow=F)
             - 1/nrow(myData) + 1)
```

The trick is constructing the right matrix for the x values.